# How to save all attachments in email using for loop in Python and Outlook?

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32

This is the code I have which is functioning perfectly fine, if I had 1 attachment in the email. The issue becomes when there are multiple attachments in the email, all of which I would like to perform functions on.

```
def get_email():
    import win32com.client
    import os
    import time
    import datetime as dt

    date_time = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")

    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetFirst()  # any time calling GetFirst(), you can get GetNext()....
    # body_content = message.body

    try:
        attachments = message.Attachments
        attachment = attachments.Item(1)
        report_name = date_time + '_' + attachment.FileName

        attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + report_name)
        print('Attachment saved: ' + report_name)

    except: #***********add error logging here**************
        print('No attachment found.')
```

How would I put this into a for loop and say - for every x, `attachment = attachments.Item(x)` - save that attachment, and run another function based on the attachment that just saved. Is there a way I can define that x variable to give me the amount of attachments in the email and then run it through the for loop? Or is there a way to run the for loop and - without producing any errors - stop once the last attachment is found?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an [Attachments collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/attachments-object-outlook) can work in a for loop, like a normal list. I got the following to save each attachment in the email and not throw errors on an email with no attachments:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import time
import datetime as dt

date_time = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()

attachments = message.Attachments

# The following line works, so you can see how many attachments are on an item
print len(attachments)
# Here's another way to get the number of attachments
print attachments.Count

# since attachments works similar to a list, a for loop works
# if there are no attachments, it won't enter the for loop, and won't throw an error
for attachment in attachments:
    report_name = date_time + '_' + attachment.FileName

    attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + report_name)
    print('Attachment saved: ' + report_name)
```